# Apache POI: get zoom level by using reflection

Tags: java, apache-poi, reflections

I want to get the current zoom level of the target sheet. By checking the docs of Apache POI, there's no getter method for the zoom level. I thought of invoking the similar methods of setting the zoom level. However I run into this problem below

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

This is my code below:

```
private static long getZoomLevel(XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception {
Method m = XSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDefaultSheetView", boolean.class);
m.setAccessible(true);
CTSheetView sheetView = (CTSheetView)m.invoke(sheet)
return sheetView.getZoomScale();
}
```

public class XSSFSheet
extends POIXMLDocumentPart
implements Sheet, OoxmlSheetExtensions:

```
private CTSheetView getDefaultSheetView(final boolean create) {
....
}
```

Any idea what causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the method with zero args, you need to pass the boolean parameter to the method

Eg

```java
m.invoke(sheet, true)
```

Comment: it should be false - if you just want to read the data from the sheet you have just parsed - with `false`, you will get `null` if there is no DefaultSheetView but you won't inadvertently create an empty one